# Is the 'non-app-store' tag valid?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, tag-abuse

I just came across the [non-app-store](/questions/tagged/non-app-store) tag. It has 4 questions. According to it's tag wiki, it indicates that the

> OP is aware that solution to his programming problem will probably
> make his application not eligible for publishing on the app-store

For the purpose of helping to

> avoid all the comments: 'you could do that but that way your app will
> never be approved...'

Is this kind of extra-info-on-the-question tag appropriate, or should we burninate the tag?

Comment: This is definitely a meta-tag. Should be burninated.

Comment: Wretched tag.  Burn with the fire of a thousand suns.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Well... I didn't expect that reaction. It has been burninated!

Comment: @RobertHarvey DOUBLE STANDARDS I SAY!